# Proper HTML to open Word document in Word without dialog

Tags: html, ms-word, internet-explorer-9

I have a simple link on a webpage, like so:

```
<a href="blah_blah.docm">Blah</a>
```

but right now it brings up a dialog with the options Open, Save, and Save As (on a left-click).

I would like it to automatically just open the document (in Word) with a left-click.  Is there a way of specifying this in the HTML instead of trying to massage registry settings on each machine?

Using Windows 7 and IE 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t. A link is a reference to a resource, not a command. The author is not supposed to control how the linked resource is processed—and cannot do that. The best you can do is to make sure that the server sends the file with a proper Internet media type (MIME type), application/msword.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder how they get PDFs to open up with just a left-click?

Comment: That's entirely a client-side setting too. Depending on what PDF reader you have installed and how the options are set you might have the type set to ‘always open in Reader’ or to open in the web browser PDF plugin. Both have security risks given the amount of PDF malware out there.